# sometimes when I ctrl+shift+i it results as "í" instead of opening inspect element

Tags: operating-system

Sometimes when I `ctrl+shift+i` it results as *í* instead of opening inspect element

https://gyazo.com/84f69c11146cd9776f8fa30a23df273a

Sometimes it fixes itself.

Comment: What “operating system” and what (browser?) application?

Comment: Windows 10, any application.